# Asp.Net Core API OpenId-Connect authentication with JWT token using IdentityModel

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, identityserver4, openid-connect, identitymodel

I have an ASP.NET Core API as back-end for an Angular SPA front-end. I am using [Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) as an Identity provider and want to create an OpenId-Connect authentication using `authorization code flow` which would mean that all the secret credentials will be stored in back-end.

The authorization flow should be like this (standard OpenID Connect flow):

1. FE application calls `/authorize` endpoint and is redirected to `Cognito` hosted UI.
2. After entering credentials FE receives an authorization code.
3. FE calls BE with authorization code.
4. BE calls `/token` endpoint and receives `accessToken` and `refreshToken`.
5. BE Returns `accessToken` to FE and sets `refreshToken` as `httpOnly` cookie(for this not sure, I may store it in Redis cache).

Then, FE with each request will add `Bearer AccessToken` to authenticate. When `AccessToken` is close to expiration, it will be updated using `refreshToken`.

I was experimenting with this [example](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/web.html) but here application used an Asp.Net Core cookie for authentication and ignored `accessToken` and `refreshToken`. I was authenticated even after `accessToken` was expired. Also, there's not much documentation on how ASP.NET cookie works.

So, now I am thinking about having my custom BE endpoints and use [IdentityModel helper methods](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html) but not sure if it is a good practice to handle authentication like this.

- `/Login` - gets `AccessToken` and `RefreshToken`
- `/Refresh` - updates `AccessToken` using `RefreshToken`. FE will call it manually when `accessToken` will be close to expiration.

**So, is there a "recommended" way to handle this scenario nicely with `IdentityModel` without writing custom implementation?**

Also, as far as I know, it is quite common to store `refreshToken` in `httpOnly` cookie which will be added to each request sent to BE but then I don't see the point of having an `accessToken` when I already have `refreshToken` added with each request.

**Isn't it better to store `refreshToken` inside BE for performance and security reasons?**

Authentication is a part of every application so I believe there should be some in-built framework functionality for `authorization code flow` as well.

Answer (score -1):

You are describing a `Backend for Frontend` approach, which is a good architecture. Make sure you separate the specialist API that deals with OAuth from general business APIs.

**RECOMMENDED WAY**

Curity have an approach that provides state-of-the-art security for SPAs, here are some links:

- [Token Handler Blog Post](https://curity.io/blog/token-handler-the-single-page-applications-new-bff/)
- [Code Example](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff)
- [Code Example Doc](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/)

We may add a .Net token handler at some point, but it should not matter what tech is used, since the idea is for the specialist API to be something you plug in rather than code.

**STORING REFRESH TOKENS**

My personal preference for SPAs is to use AES256 encrypted HTTP only cookies. This fits nicely with goals of avoiding OAuth plumbing in applications and enables the token handler to be stateless and easier to deploy + manage.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I don't have a resource server? I have an API server and I want to do authentication there because a separate proxy server will highly increase complexity of the whole system.